# How to get spannable from Html.fromHtml(spannable) when HTML got quotation marks tags

Tags: java, android, html

Im making a Notepad app, and I've got some problem with HTML converting.

In my notepad app user is able to format text via Spannable object.
I need to convert Spannable object to String when I'm putting it into DB Table via Html.toHtml() method.

When I'm trying to convert String back into Spannable via Html.fromHtml() method it ignores all tags that are using quotation marks in it.

For example:

I've got Spannable converted to Html that is able to change text size and it looks like this:

```
"<p dir="ltr"><font size ="6">HERE IS TEXT</font><p>\n"
```

After converting:

[image]

(Sorry for image, Stackoverflow were apllying my HTML code here, lol)

It works fine when im using tags without quotation marks like:

```
<p dir="ltr"><u>HERE IS TEXT</u></p>\n"
```

Do u know any solution for that or I need another way to serialize my Spannable object to String to get it into my SQLite DB?